# how to solve following problem in C++?

Tags: c++

I have one template function which will take a pointer type and i have instantiated it before calling.
i have written function with its dummy implementation as follows:

```
template<T>fun_name( const T *p )
{
  //written functionality which will give me class name that i will store into string Variable
  e.g. i got output like this string Var = "First_class" or string Var = "Second_class"   

  //Using this class name i will call one function of that class
    if(Var == "Fisrt_class") 
    {   
    First_class::static_function_name(p);
    }
    if(Var == "Second_class")
    { 
    Second_class::static_function_name(p);
    }

}
```

and in global scope i instantiated this function for two variables as like below:

```
template<first_class>static_function_name(const First_class *)
template<Second_class>static_function_name(const Second_class *)
```

above code gives me error that

```
error: no matching function call in Second_class::static_function_class(const Fisrt_class*)
error: no matching function call in First_class::static_function_class(const Second_class*)
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: `//Using this class name i will call one function of that class if(Var == "Fisrt_class") {` should be `//Using this class name i will call one function of that class if(Var == "First_class") {` (typo on the string)

Comment: Balaji, can you be more clear with the question. I am not understanding what you are trying to convey here.

Comment: you different code samples aren't consistent. Please try to come up with a single short source file that shows the problem and post the result.

Comment: simple thisg is that can we replace string variable with its content??? e.g. string Var = "Fisrt_class", //calling function Var::static_fun_name(*p), can we replace var with its content i.e. "First Class"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this :

```
template<typename T> // template<class T> is equally valid!
void fun_name( const T *p )
{
  T::static_function_name(p);
}
```

is enough!

Two more errors is fixed in the above code:

- Mention the keyword `typename` in `template<T>` in your code. You can also write `template<class T>` which is equally valid.
- Mention the return type of the function template as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your function template "calls" each of the static functions in each class. Even though program flow may never get to one of the calls, the compiler still has to figure out the code for each of them.

So when you instantiate:

```
template<first_class>fun_name(const first_class*)
```

the compiler tries to compile the *entire* function with T = first_class, which means at some point inside the function, it will try to compile the function call:

```
Second_class::static_function_name(p);
```

But since variable `p` is a pointer to `first_class`, the compiler doesn't find the function.

If you want conditional compilation, try specializing your function instead so the compiler only compiles the function call you intended for each type:

```
template <T> fun_name (const T* p);
template <> fun_name<first_class>(const first_class* p) {
    first_class::static_function_name(p);
}
template <> fun_name<second_class>(const second_class* p) {
    second_class::static_function_name(p);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use member functions which seem to be intended for what you are trying to do here. Then you can create objects and call the functions directly:

```
first_class f;
second_class s;

f.function();
s.function();
```

Comment: thanks but i can't separate it out, also can't create the objets of that class

Comment: Ok. Then specializing the function templates is what you want to do, instead of using the if statement.

Comment: simple thing is that can we replace string variable with its content??? e.g. string Var = "Fisrt_class", //calling function Var::static_fun_name(*p), can we replace Var with its content i.e. "First Class"

Comment: specialization is not needed. See my solution!

Answer (score -1):

try changing to ,

```
template<typename T>
void fun_name( const T *p )
{
  T::static_function_name(p);
}
```

Comment: @wvwww will not woek.... i have to get class name from pointer and then call function